# converting to .jar file Bluetooth Low Energy for Processing Android

Tags: processing

I followed https://github.com/joshuajnoble/blepdroid for converting a library in to .jar file, so that it can be used for processing.

I am relatively new to android studio and I did not understand how to convert an rfduino library into a .jar file so that it can be added to the processing software libraries.

Could anyone help me with the procedure to get this done?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add the Android Mode to Processing if you haven't done so already. Click the button top right edge of the editor that says Java, click **Add Mode...**, then search and install **Android Mode**:

[image: Android Mode]

Once that's installed you will be prompted to browse to the **Android SDK** on your computer.

As soon as this part is configured, you should be able to compile your first Processing Android app!

What's left to do is install the BLE_pDroid library:

1. Download the [latest release](https://github.com/joshuajnoble/blepdroid/releases)
2. Unzip it(blepdroid-0.1.zip)
3. rename the folder to `blepdroid`(removing any version from the folder name)
4. Restart Processing
5. Start writing your first BLE_pDroid based app or explore the Examples (via File > Examples > Contributed Libraries)

No need for Android Studio/eclipse unless you want to, in which case, with your BLE_pDroid Processing Android project open go to **File > Export Android Project**